# How to schedule a task at midnight and the other tasks every hour in the same DAG

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I wonder if it is possible to use different schedulers in a single DAG, I explain my use case: A task which will be executed every day at midnight to **create a file** (a new file every day) and the other tasks will be executed every hour to **append data** into file.

As you notice I have two `scheduler_interval`

`0 0 * * *` (Every day at midnight)  => create a new file

`0 * * * *` (Every hour)  => append data

Any idea to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the python branch operator to solve your problem. This python branch operator will check if the current time is midnight then go to create a file task else go to the task to append data into the file. The scheduler should be hourly.